# Address-of operator in C

Tags: c

In C programming, does the address-of operator `&` result in object's first address?

For example:

```c
int a[2] = {10, 20};   
int* arrays_first_address = &a;
```

As `&a` means "array's first address" then can I generalize it so the address-of operator results in object's first address?

Comment: Yes, it's the address of the start of the object. What else would it be?

Comment: Yes, `a` will point to the first byte of the first element in your array. It is always the address of the first byte of first member/element of a struct/array etc.

Comment: (Oversimplification warning): An object does not have a "first address", it only has a single address. _Object identity_ can be defined as address equality.

Comment: `int a = {10, 20};` is the same as `int a = 10;`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a subtle difference between `a` and `&a`.

`a` is an array which in most expressions decays into a pointer to its first element, `int*` in this case. Meaning that writing `a` and `&a[0]` is 100% equivalent in most contexts.

`&a` is one of the exceptions where array decay does not happen, so you get a pointer to an array, type `int(*)[2]`. This can be regarded as "a pointer to the whole array" rather than just the first item. It is not compatible with `int*`, which is the reason why your code isn't valid C. (No it *doesn't* compile fine, it's a constraint violation, please see [What must a C compiler do when it finds an error?](https://software.codidact.com/posts/277340))

However, the whole array and the first item in that array are naturally located at the very same address. So no matter pointer type you will get the same address.

Answer (score -1):

I suggest to run this program :

```
    int a[2] = {10, 20};
    
    printf("a=%p\n", a);
    printf("&a=%p\n", &a);
    printf("&(a[0])=%p\n", &(a[0]) );
```

And you should have answer.

In C, an array is also see as a pointer, but there is no memory really alloc with this value. So it's a convention to says that "a" and "&a" have the same value.